# How to split a column into two columns in SSIS if any invalid data in the column

Tags: ssis

Iam trying to load data from CSV file and dumping into database. While reading date values column from the CSV file getting some error because of CSV file contains some invalid data like '31-FEB-2014'.So i need to store those invalid data into another column in the table, how to achieve it using SSIS.Please assist.

Comment: how you identified it is invalid data?  on which basis ? Date Format ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new column on your table which is of datatype nvarchar. Map your CSV Source column to the new column.

Then afterwards you can do some magic. Example you could use a derived column to handle the new nvarchar value and convert it back to a decent date format and then map it to your original column.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to redirect it. See the red arrow and drag it to other destination like below:

[image: n1]

Set properties like below:

[image: n2]

tag me incase you're stuck.